# Installing Postgresql 8.3.7 in Debian Squeeze

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, debian-squeeze

I am tring to install postgresql-8.3.7 into Debian Squeeze OS.  It is throws me following error. unmet dependency  libkrb53, libpq5 . Whether postgresql-8.3.7 is compatible with Debian Squeeze operating system. If it is compatible, what should I do to install postgresql-8.3.7 . Please suggest any idea.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known problem in ubuntu, the name of libkrb53 changed to libkrb5-3. I suggest you download and install the library from [this link](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libkrb53), this is how someone solved it in ubuntu. If it still gives you an error, make a symlink pointing to libkrb5-3 called libkrb53.

You can get libpq5 from [here](http://packages.debian.org/stable/libpq5).

Although your best option is to go with the latest version of Postgres from the repo's unless you really need that version.

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql 8.3.7 is not in the sqeeze version, it is postgresql 8.4. So how do you install this specific version ? Why don't install the last release with `apt-get install postgresql` ?

Comment: I added lenny packages cd's in the synaptic package manager.

Comment: Could you go to postgresql 8.4 ?